# DAOs and SOLID design principles

Tags: oop, dao, solid-principles

I've been reading up about SOLID design principles, currently looking at the 'Single Responsibilty Principle', but I was curious on the use case for this principle. At the company I work at, we have DAOs which have methods of `read`, `insert` & `update` to manage a record in the database.

Would something like this break the 'Single Responsibilty Principle'? If so, would you then need classes for each inserting, reading & updating?

Example DAO:

```
class UserDAO {
    public function read(where: object) {
        // read code
    }

    public function insert(user: User) {
        // insert code
    }

    public function update(user: User) {
        // update code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single Responsibility Principle states that

> A class must have only one reason to change.

Let's say we have  **UserDAO** with methods read, save, delete, update. So, this class will only be changed when there will be changes related to User. So, it has a single reason for a change i.e User.

So, I think it doesn't violate SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) if implemented correctly.

```
void save(User user){
//user related logic
}

void save(User user){
// user related logic and address logic encapsulated inside address class
//eg: address.getAddress(user.getId);
}
```

In the above case, it doesn't violate SRP because the save method will only be changed when there is a change in User logic. The address logic is handled by Address class per se.

For eg: if save method looks like:

```
void save(User user){
Address address = new Address();
 //Address logic
 Payment payment = new Payment();
 //Payment logic
}
```

In the above code, any changes in Address or Payment logic will make this DAO save method change as well. It violates SRP.

So, it really depends on the implementation.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah that makes a lot of sense. Guess I was thinking about a method level, but thinking about it would be pretty stupid to have a class per method